# Ubuntu not detecting particular wifi (dual boot, Macbook)

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, macbook

This is not a question, but to provide a solution to people suffering this problem. I've tried every step suggested out there, but none of them worked.

To describe my issue, I have a Macbook Pro, duel boot (Ubuntu or MacOS). Ubuntu detected available wifi networks, except for the particular one that I am trying to connect to (in my case, it was a public wifi). The strange part was, that wifi was detectable from MacOS.

One suggested solution was that the preferred wifi on MacOS may crash with the one on Ubuntu, so you should delete the preferred wifi on MacOS. So, I deleted it by "system preference > network > advance > delete the wifi with minus sign > apply". But this did not resolve my issue. And then after several days I realized that, whenever I restarted, the deleted wifi kept reappearing! So, I googled it to find out how to permanently deleted the saved wifi, and one suggestion was to uncheck the "iCloud keychain" from "system preference > icloud". But my keychain had already been unchecked. I wasn't exactly sure where the past wifi is coming from, so I just logged out my iCould account from Mac. After I switched to Ubuntu, it finally detected the wifi I want!

To sum up, **sign out your iCloud account on Mac.** This is a simple solution, but took me a whole week to resolve this. I am posting this to save some time for others. Also, if someone knows how to delete the past wifi without logging out on MacOS, please let us know.

Comment: Does the MacOS show what channel the wifi was on when Ubuntu could find it?  It could be an issue with the driver not being allowed to use certain channels, like a channel higher than 11 on 2.4GHz

Comment: Please [edit] your post so that it is only a question, the post the answer parts below.